# Scheme - Splitting a list into two equal lists

Tags: list, split, scheme, equals

Problem:

Write a function (split l) that takes a list and partitions it into two equal-sized (within one) lists, and returns a pair whose car is the first list and whose cdr is the second list.

My code:

```
(define split list)
  (let ((half (/ (length list) 2)
    (cons (car half list)
          (cdr half list))))
```

Comment: I'm don't think that code really counts as an attempt. It's not syntactically correct, and it wouldn't run even if it were.  `car` takes one argument, not two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another possible implementation using the [tortoise and hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) algorithm:

```
(define (split lst)
  (let loop ((tortoise lst) (hare lst) (acc '()))
    (if (or (null? hare) (null? (cdr hare)))
        (cons (reverse acc) tortoise)
        (loop (cdr  tortoise) 
              (cddr hare) 
              (cons (car tortoise) acc)))))
```

The above solution has the advantage of traversing the list only *once*, notice that we don't need to know the length of the list to make the split. It's called "tortoise and hare" because we keep two pointers over the list: one advances slowly, one element at a time (the "tortoise") and the other goes faster, two elements at a time (the "hare"). The algorithm stops when the hare reaches the end of the input list.

Alternatively, we can implement a more idiomatic (albeit slower) solution using built-in procedures. Assuming that the [`take`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._take%29%29) and [`drop`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._drop%29%29) procedures are available in your interpreter (if not, import them from [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)), this is closer to what you had in mind:

```
(define (split lst)
  (let ((half (quotient (length lst) 2)))
    (cons (take lst half)
          (drop lst half))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(split '(1 2 3 4))   
=> ((1 2) 3 4)

(split '(1 2 3 4 5)) 
=> ((1 2) 3 4 5)
```

Comment: but if take and drop aren't given, and i'm not allowed to import them, how would i write a code?

Comment: @user27 then either use the first version of my code or implement your own versions of `take` and `drop`, they're not that difficult (see the linked documentation to have an idea of what they must do). Use as a guide SRFI-1's [source code](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/chicken-core/blob/master/srfi-1.scm).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(define (splitAt n lst)
    (let loop ((acc '()) (n n) (lst lst))
        (if (or (= n 0) (null? lst)) (cons (reverse acc) lst)
            (loop (cons (car lst) acc) (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))

(define (split lst) (splitAt (quotient (length lst) 2) lst))
```

It works as follows:

```
(split '(1 2 3 4))   => ((1 2) 3 4)
(split '(1 2 3 4 5)) => ((1 2) 3 4 5)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a bad idea to name a parameter `list`, it clashes with the built-in `list` procedure.

Comment: It doesn't matter because I'm not using the built-in `list` procedure at all.

Comment: @AaditMShah Bad habits matter. They'll bite you sooner or later.

Comment: @uselpa Alright. I updated my answer to use the correct coding conventions. Thank you. Appreciated.